# Simulation based on BSTS model

Tags: simulation, prediction-interval, forecast-combination, bsts

Currently I'm fitting different time series models and produce combined n-step-ahead forecasts. As finding prediction intervals (analytically) for combined forecasts is quite a hassle, I decided to simulate a sufficient number of paths from each model of the desired length n, combine them as I do for the actual n-step-ahead forecast, and then calculate the desired quantiles (which should yield the prediction interval) for each of the n points.

And now to the question:

One of the above models is BSTS from the bsts package in R. Does anyone know how to simulate paths based on a bsts model in R? My current working solution to this problem is to calculate all quantiles from 0.0001 to .9999 by .0001 for each point in time and then randomly select paths of length n. However, I doubt that this is the best way to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is using the `distribution` attribute of the `bsts.prediction` object. That will give you "paths" of length set by your forecast horizon.

```
p <- predict(model)
p$distribution
```

where `p$distribution` has size [number of MCMC steps, forecast horizon], so `p$distribution[i,]` contains "path" $i$.